# How to revert a commit but to a specific folder?

Tags: git

I've made commits such that

commit hash - hash1 -> changes = `a/1.txt, a/2.txt, b/1.txt`

Now I'm reverting this commit by  `git revert -m 1 hash1` but I want to remove only changes done to folder `a/` but want to retain the changes inside `b/`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--no-commit`.

```
git revert --no-commit <commit_id>
git restore --staged b/
git checkout .
git commit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git revert -m 1 hash1
# If needed, resolve conflicts and commit;
# those outside of a/ may be resolved arbitrarily.
git reset --hard HEAD^
git checkout hash1 a/
git commit -C HEAD@{1}
```

You could also use `revert -n` and then reset all other directories before committing; the recipe above is preferable only if there are many such other directories since it names only `a`.